# *How to login to VMWare Infrastructure Web access without username and password

Tags: vmware-server, firefox

When I am on the local machine I want to access the VMWare Infrastructure Web access without typing username and password.

The old gui console from the 1.x series could just connect locally without that.

Another solution would be if Firefox somehow stored the login, but somethng prevents it. The Firefox password manager does not work.

*Edit:* The accepted answer shows how to do it on  windows host, see below. If you need to find the file on a linux host maybe this helps you:

```
/usr/lib/vmware/webAccess/tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.16/webapps/ui/jslib-1.0.128374/modules/com.vmware.webaccess.app_1.0.0
```

This is the directory where the file WebAccess.properties lives on a Ubuntu 8.04 LTS host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can find this file :

C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Server\tomcat\webapps\ui\jslib-1.0.128374\modules\com.vmware.webaccess.app_1.0.0\WebAccess.properties

...edit it, and find the following lines (near the end of the file)

```
new Object({
   login_url: "http://localhost:8222/sdk",
   login_show_webservice_url: "false",
   login_name: "",
   login_password: ""
});
```

...and add your username and password - e.g. (username being myDomain\testUser, and password being P@ssword1)

```
new Object({
   login_url: "http://localhost:8222/sdk",
   login_show_webservice_url: "false",
   login_name: "myDomain\\testUser",
   login_password: "P@ssword1"
});
```

Note the double backslash...

HTH .. Ken

**EDIT:   Hmmm it seem like this may only work with IE (doesn't seem to work in FF3.5)**

Comment: Actually it does do it on FF3.5 - my mistake earlier...

The only thing I have not been able to do is to get it into the VMRC client

Glad to help .. Ken

Answer (score 0):

My problem is that I missed where the name and password came from originally. I've tried everything I can think of--my vmware.com (for VMware Server) username (email address) and password, a username (but not password) I typed in when I installed VMware on Windows 7, etc. When did I say what this should be and where?

Comment: did you try a windows administrator account? like "Administrator" - "Administrator's password" or the windows acccount that runs the vmware service?